# Tomcat 4.1.24, slf4j 1.6.4, and activemq 5.5.1 Incompatibilities

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, activemq-classic, slf4j

I'm running into the following error when attempting to initialize a JMS connection between a servlet on Tomcat and a local ActiveMQ instace.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.warn(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:420)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory.createTransport(TcpTransportFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.doConnect(TransportFactory.java:141)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.doConnect(TransportFactory.java:51)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.connect(TransportFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:243)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:258)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:230)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:208) ...
```

I believe all my dependencies are in order. Other threads have suggested it's a problem with mismatched slf4j jar libraries. Here is my lib directory.

```
root@TestDebS:/usr/local/jakarta-tomcat-4.1.24/webapps/examples/WEB-INF# ls lib/
activemq-all-5.5.1.jar   exolabcore-0.3.5.jar   jndi_1.2.1.jar    openjms-0.7.5.jar    slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
classes12.zip            exolabcore-0.3.7.jar   log4j-1.2.14.jar  openjms-0.7.6.1.jar  slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar
comm.jar                 javax.comm.properties  log4j-1.2.8.jar   openjms-0.7.6.jar    xercesImpl.jar
commons-logging-api.jar  jms_1.0.2a.jar         servlet.jar
```

Both [tomcat root]/common/lib and [tomcat root]/shared/lib have nothing noteworthy in them. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: You have multiple versions of multiple libraries in your `WEB-INF/lib`; this is a *bad* idea. Also, you must not deploy your own `servlet.jar` if that's the servlet API. May not solve *this* problem, but it will certainly stop others from occurring.

Comment: Was actually in the process of cleaning that up when you sent this. Unfortunately I've been tasked w/ cleaning up another developer's mess.

Comment: @DaveNewton Could you post this in an answer? It actually led to me finding the answer, so I feel like you deserve the check. I can also edit it after and add details on exactly how I found the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: I'll move it to an answer, but just upvote it unless it's really, really close--you can answer your own question and accept it if I just provided a nudge. (It sounds weird, but that's just how SO works :)

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I know how it usually works, but I guess it was my OCD trying to give credit where credit is due. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple versions of multiple libraries in your WEB-INF/lib; this is a bad idea as it can lead to mixing-and-matching of the different versions depending on which versions contain specific signatures.

Also, you must not deploy your own servlet.jar if that's the servlet API. The errors this causes are often non-obvious. May not solve this problem, but it will certainly stop others from occurring.